# how to display pagination like "previous 1 2...7 next"

Tags: pagination, ee

i want to display pagination in blog section like following way

```
 <previous 1 2......7 next>
```

Can anyone help me for display pagination like above pattern

Thank You.
Dhvanit N. Dave

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/pagination.html) you'll find an example that is essentially exactly what you are looking for.

```
{paginate}
  {pagination_links}
    <ul>
      {first_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
      {/first_page}

      {previous_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
      {/previous_page}

      {page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
      {/page}

      {next_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
      {/next_page}

      {last_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
      {/last_page}
    </ul>
  {/pagination_links}
{/paginate}
```